# availability of snmp agent in network device

Tags: java, snmp

I have list of active deviceses in lan network... by its ip address how can I know that, Is snmp agent available on that device???
please help me find the list of snmp agent enable devices's list....
I want to do it using java (snmp4j)......

Answer (score 1):

The only way to test if an agent on the device is to either know it (because the documentation says it has an agent) or to try and access it.  But to try and access it you need to know *how* to access it.

If you're using SNMPv1 and SNMPv2c then you'll need to know the community name that can be used to get to the data.  Some devices default to the community string with "public" but more and more devices, fortunately, no longer do this (and they shoudn't...  from a security perspective no one should have ever done this).

For SNMPv3, you'd need to know even more parameters.  But SNMPv3 with USM does have a probing method where you can send an initial packet with limited information in order to discover it's engineID.  Because of this, SNMPv3 actually allows discovery unless the discovery mechanisms has been disabled.

Most commercial management suites have special code for doing discovery and network mapping, but all of them require at least configuration for trying various community names or default SNMPv3 settings.

In the end, you still need to know the devices you deployed and what they're capable of.